# Avoid logout when reload page with react and laravel sanctum

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm creating a project that involves a login. I am using react for fronted, laravel for backend and laravel sanctum for authentication. How do I keep the user logged in when I reload the page? The general state is managed by context api

this is my login function in laravel

```
  public function login(Request $request)
{
    $fields = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    //estraggo l'user con la mail inserita
    $user = User::where('email', $fields['email'])->first();

    //controllo se l'user esiste e poi se la password inserita e quella nel database corrispondono
    if ($user && Hash::check($fields['password'], $user->password)) {
        Auth::login($user);
    } else {
        return response([
            'message' => 'Wrong credentials'
        ], 401);
    }

    $token = $user->createToken('myapptoken')->plainTextToken;

    $response = [
        'user' => $user,
        'token' => $token,
        'message' => 'logged in',
    ];

    return response($response);
}
```

This is my login function in react

```
    const { loginUser } = useAuth();
  const emailRef = useRef("");
  const passwordRef = useRef("");
  const cookies = new Cookies();
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = emailRef.current.value;
    const password = passwordRef.current.value;

    const userData = {
      email,
      password,
    };

    loginUser(userData);

    //reset values
    emailRef.current.value = "";
    passwordRef.current.value = "";
  };
```

these are my functions in context api that handle login

```
const loginMutation = useMutation(login, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      setAccessToken(data.data.token);
      const token = data.data.token;
      setUserId(data.data.user.id);
      setUserName(data.data.user.name);
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
      console.log(token);
      localStorage.setItem("accessToken", token);
      localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", true);
      // localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', true);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      console.error("errore duarente il login:", error.response.data);
    },
  });

  const loginUser = async (userData) => {
    try {
      await loginMutation.mutateAsync(userData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("errore durante il login");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the `localStorage` in order to implement a persisting login state. You can follow the steps mentioned in this [article][1]:

Basically, whenever a user logs in, a `value` is stored locally in the user's browser with a corresponding `key`. Whenever the app reloads, you place a check whether the user's localStorage still has the value to the key and if it does, the app won’t start from the beginning again. This is a common pattern but I'm a little sceptical about its level of security. Although, you can easily find that out online. The solution works great on the frontend. Good luck!

[1]: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-persist-a-logged-in-user-in-react/#:~:text=useEffect(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20const%20loggedInUser,first%20time%20the%20app%20loads.